# Assign a 8 Bit Array to an element of 8 Byte Array

Tags: c, arrays, stm32

I have the array: `TxMessage.Data[8]`, each element of this array is 1 byte. So the length of  `TxMessage.Data` array is 8Byte total. I have another array: `ActiveBits[8]` which has lentgh of 8 bit. Each element of `ActiveBits[i]` is 1 bit and can be only `0` or `1`.

So i want to assign `ActiveBits[0 to 7]` arrays elements to `TxMessage.Data[1]`.How can i do that?

Comment: How do you create an array of 8 bits?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: `ActiveBits[0 to 8]`..off-by-one

Comment: I just created like; uint8_t ActiveBits[8] ; and assigned its elements to 0 or 1

Comment: Yes but you index it `[0..7]` not `[0..8]`.

Comment: Sorry didnt see that, fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you do **not** have an array of 8 bits, as that is not possible in C **in a standard way**. Since C99 You might have, however:

```
_Bool ActiveBits[8];  // bool if you use stdbool.h
```

Where each value is a boolean. For this, you can simply:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t data = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) {
    data <<= 1;
    data |= ActiveBits[i];
}
TxMessage.Data[1] = data;
```

This will pack the bits big endian (MSB first). You should make clear if that is what you really want. The loop can be easily changed to little endian, however.

This works, as in C, `_Bool` is an integer type with values `0`/`1` (`_True`/`_False`) only. However, `_Bool` is still not necessarily a single bit. That depends ont the ABI/PCS (or compiler/toolchain if unspecified). ARM AAPCS uses uint8_t, for instance.

If that is no `_Bool` array, but any other integer type, change the line to:

```
    data |= !!barray[i];
```

This will first negate (boolean) the value: `0` becomes `1`, any other becomes `0`. Then it negates again, changing `0` to `1` and vice versa. Modern compilers will detect this pattern and optimize it. You can, of course, also use:

```
    data |= barray[i] != 0;
```

Whatever you prefer.

Comment: @abdullahcinar: Yeah, I notices while editing. Please read again and remove the downvote (if you did).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the array ActiveBits[8] into a byte and store it into TxMessage.Data[1]

```
unsigned char raw_byte;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
raw_byte |= ActiveBits[i]; 
raw_byte = raw_byte << 1;  // or raw_byte = raw_byte >> 1; depending on how you want your data to be manipulated
}

TxMessage.Data[1] = raw_byte;
```

Comment: cant i use `uint8_t raw_byte` ? it worked like that.

Comment: @abdullahcinar: See my answer, that would actually be the prefered type to use. Note, however, as I stated in my answer, this will pack the bits big-endian (lower index becomes higer bit-number). You have to make sure the receiver will interpret this correctly! This is a major failure when serialising data structures.

Comment: Certainly this is not correct as `raw_byte` will always have its LSBit cleared.  Suggest shift before `|=`.  `raw_byte` not initialized.

Comment: this code has something wrong, tried this and there is a shifting problem

Comment: Yes you can use ui8_t also, i thought your library dont have uint8_t